# Can I say "I earned an interest of 5000 dollars from my savings account"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

When a word refers to "**an amount of money**", that word is often countable.

Fro example,

[debt](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/debt?q=debt): [countable] a sum of money that somebody owes

[rent](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rent_1?q=rent): [uncountable, countable] an amount of money that you regularly pay so that you can use a house, room, etc.

[investment](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/investment?q=investment): [countable, uncountable] the money that you invest, or the thing that you invest in

[loan](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/loan): [countable] an amount of money that you borrow from a bank etc

all these words can be said in the form of "**a Noun + of + $$$**".

For example,

*I have a debt of 200 dollars*

*I pay a rent of 1000 dollars a month*

*I have an investment of 2 million dollars in stock*

*I took out a loan of £60,000*

Now, "**interest**" also means "**the money...**" but it is uncountable

> [interest](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/interest) 4 [uncountable]
>
> a) the extra money that you must pay back when you borrow money
> interest on
>
> The interest on the loan is 16% per year.
>
> How much are the monthly interest payments?
>
> b) money paid to you by a bank or financial institution when you keep
> money in an account there
>
> an account that pays higher interest
>
> The more you save, the more interest you’ll earn.

My question is:

**Why is "interest" just uncountable and not countable?**

**Can I say "*I earned an interest of 5000 dollars from my savings account*"?**

Comment: Please clarify what you're looking for. Are you looking for some rule of English to explain it? Or a logic-based reason? Or do you want a historical reason?

Comment: There are not usually many good answers to "why" questions about English.  The best we can say is that general concepts or phenomena are usually uncountable.

Comment: The [etymology of "interest"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/interest) is interesting: in English it originally meant a legal claim or right, from a French word for damage, loss, or harm, and came to mean compensation for default on a debt, and later the modern sense of a regular payment for a loan. See also David Graeber's *Debt* for much more. But that doesn't explain why it's uncountable.

Comment: If you want to sound like you don't know English, by all means: a Noun + of + $$$". **No, interest does not mean money**; **interest is a percentage of some amount of money**. And, fyi, we use: a $200 debt, a $5,000 loan, we don't use the word of for these things. I pay $1,000 dollars in rent per month. When are you going to close out all your questions?

Comment: @Lambie, most dictionaries have examples such as "a debt of $$$", so that way of saying is not wrong

Comment: Dictionaries do not internalize usage. They aren't writers: How to get a $5,000 personal loan. https://www.bankrate.com/loans/personal-loans/how-to-get-a-5000-personal-loan. //Yours is not "wrong", it's just not how business uses these terms.

Comment: World Bank Will Sell $100 Million 2-Year Bond Issue [title], Body of article: a $100 million issue of United States dollar bonds. https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/1962/09/14/world-bank-will-sell-100-million-usd-2-year-bond-issue  You either want to learn this stuff or not. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not say "I earned an interest of 5000 dollars from my savings account". Uncountable nouns can sometimes be preceded by indefinite articles, but in this case doing so would not make sense. A correct, common way of expressing this idea is:

> I earned 5000 dollars in interest from my savings account.

I have no idea why "interest" (when it has this meaning) is uncountable. I think that the reasons for why many words are countable or uncountable have been lost to time.